# Getting a date from string objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

How can i get a date from the following date "2014-05-16T16:15:07+01:00"

I used NSDateFormatter as shown below but it didnt work. It gives null as a result.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
```

Comment: There are countless existing questions on parsing this date format. Please search. And why do you quote the `Z` in your format? Does your date string have a `Z` literal in it? No.

Comment: There is this really exciting new thing called "Google".  You might give it a try.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the info was readily available to the OP if he'd only looked for it.

Comment: @HotLicks i already google it but all the date formatter i have test return a nil value

Comment: @rmaddy No and i already test with a yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ in vain

Comment: Why do you think that using `Z` is the proper format? Please look at the official docs that describe all of the date format specifiers and see what is needed to handle timezones with a format such as `+01:00`. Hint - it's not a single `Z`.

Comment: If you search through the documentation for NSDateFormatter it eventually leads you to the document that describes date format strings.  Learn to use the documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks if you try to search before you start guessing that will be great, because i have already search in the documentation with no result.

Comment: That's odd, because I found it, starting from the NSDateFormatter page.  You just have to put some effort into it.

Comment: I know this question has nothing to do with MagicalRecord but the duplicate question involves the same date format and the proper answer.

Comment: That will surprise me, i'm pretty sure that will not work

Comment: NSDateFormatter page.  Click on Data Formatting Guide.  Click on Date Formatters.  Scroll down and see "Fixed Formats".  Select the line that corresponds to your release.  QED.

Comment: @NabilEl Why don't you think that will work for you? Did you try it?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes and the result is null

Comment: @HotLicks déjà vu nothing new

Comment: @NabilEl Update your question with the latest code you tried. Be sure you include code that logs that actual string you tried to convert to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around `Z` in your date format string:

```
NSString *sDate = @"2014-05-16T16:15:07+01:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"]; // 5 Zs is technically correct here.
NSDate *result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];

NSLog(@"result: %@", result); //result: 2014-05-16 15:15:07 +0000
```

When you quote the Z, the date formatter expects a literal 'Z' character in the input string rather than the time zone as an offset from GMT, which is what your date string contains.

Comment: the return is "result: (null)"

Comment: @NabilEl, Not on my 10.9.3 machine. The code in my answer, and the output in the comment on the NSLog line was copied and pasted directly from a source code file which I compiled and ran, and its output. You can see the whole thing here: https://gist.github.com/armadsen/0c93770b2d70b340c081